# Add Multiple Identities in ClaimsPrincipal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, wif, claims-based-identity

I see a lot of code like the following to create a new ClaimsIdentity and ClaimsPrincipal

```
var claims = new List<Claim>() {
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Me"),
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "email@me.com"),
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
};

var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Forms");
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(id);
```

This is straightforward and there are lots of examples on the web about how to do this. What I would like to do and am not finding much documentation about is how to have multiple identities within ClaimsPrincipal. ClaimsPrincipal is defined like the following so clearly it supports multiple identities.

```
public class ClaimsPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
  public virtual IEnumerable<ClaimsIdentity> Identities { get; }
  ...
}
```

I am thinking that the above approach of declaring var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(id) is not sufficient because I need to be able to add an identity to a ClaimsPrincipal that may already have an identity. So what happens if you already have an identity in ClaimsPrincipal and declare a new instance of ClaimsPrincipal? Do you now have two instances of ClaimsPrincipal with different identities? My hunch is that is the case, so instead I would need to check for the existence of the current ClaimsPrincipal and add to it like so:

```
ClaimsPrincipal principal;
if(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current != null)
{
   principal = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
   principal.AddIdentity(id)

}
else
{
   principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(id);
}
```

Am I on the right track here? Can anybody provide insight into what goes on under the hood when there are multiple identities in ClaimsPrincipal, If I am not on the right track can you offer suggestions on how I might go about using multiple identities within ClaimsPrincipal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Remove ClaimsIdentity From ClaimsPrincipal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685719/how-to-remove-claimsidentity-from-claimsprincipal)

Comment: They are not duplicates. One is asking how to add an identity, one is about removing an identity. Similar, but there are different considerations involved.

Answer (score 2):

There is a constructor, which will do it for you:

```
public ClaimsPrincipal(IEnumerable<ClaimsIdentity> identities)
```

However, the semantics of this are undefined. Microsoft hasn't used it so far and I was never able to serialize it into an interoperable SAML token...... I am not sure what SesAM will do with it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I saw that, but couldn't figure out how to use it. What I ended up doing was getting the identities collection directly from the token and adding or removing identities at that level, then recreating the ClaimsPrincipal from the collection of ClaimsIdenties. Something like this: identities = handler.ValidateToken(token, cookieHandler.Path). I'll update with my question over the weekend the code I ended up with.

Comment: It can get confusing when you add multiple identities with Subject claim and then attempt to retrieve the Subject claim from the Principal - which one should it return? ClaimsPrincipal has default primary Identity, but not sure, who and how should set it in case of multiple identities.